# Maximum of two Independent Random Variables with Erlang distribution

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, random-variables, gamma-distribution

While I am deriving the maximum of two Erlang Indepenent random variables 
$$
  z =
\begin{cases}
l,  & \text{if $l$>$h$ and  $l$>0}  \\
h,  & \text{if $h$>$l$ and  $l$>0} \\
h, & \text{if  $l$<0}
\end{cases}
$$
$$
E[z]= \int_0^\infty \int_{h=l}^\infty h f(h)f(l) dh dl +  \int_0^\infty \int_{h=0}^l h f(h)f(l) dh dl + \int_{-\infty}^0 \int_{h=0}^\infty h f(h)f(l) dh dl
$$
However,  $l$ will not be less than zero since it is representing a time period.
for this condition how can I simplify this term $$\int_{-\infty}^0 \int_{h=0}^\infty h f(h)f(l) dh dl$$ to only represent $l=0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erlang random variables have a non-negative support.   So because both $H$ and $L$ are Erlang RV, therefore:
$$\begin{align}
Z & = \begin{cases} H & : 0\leq L \leq H \\ L & : 0\leq H < L\\ 0 & : \textsf{otherwise}\end{cases}
\\[2ex]
\mathsf E(Z) & = \int_0^\infty \int_h^\infty l f(h)f(l)\operatorname d l\operatorname d h + \int_0^\infty \int_0^h h f(h)f(l)\operatorname d l\operatorname d h \\[2ex] & = 2\int_0^\infty h f(h)\int_0^h f(l)\operatorname d l\operatorname d h & \textsf{by symmetry} \end{align}$$

Comment: Is there a difference between saying $$ 0\leq L \leq H $$ and  $$0< L < H $$

Comment: There is, but when dealing with a continuous random variable the probabilities are the same.